# why is my simple feedforward neural network diverging (pytorch)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am experimenting with a simple 2 layer neural network with pytorch, feeding in only three inputs of size 10 each, with a single value as output. I have normalised inputs and lowered learning rate. It is my understanding that a two layer fully connected neural network should be able to trivially fit to this data

```
Features:

0.8138  1.2342  0.4419  0.8273  0.0728  2.4576  0.3800  0.0512  0.6872  0.5201
1.5666  1.3955  1.0436  0.1602  0.1688  0.2074  0.8810  0.9155  0.9641  1.3668
1.7091  0.9091  0.5058  0.6149  0.3669  0.1365  0.3442  0.9482  1.2550  1.6950
[torch.FloatTensor of size 3x10]


Targets
[124, 125, 122]
[torch.FloatTensor of size 3]
```

The code is adapted from a simple example and I am using MSELoss as the loss function. The loss diverges to infinity after just a few iterations:

```
features = torch.from_numpy(np.array(features))

x_data = Variable(torch.Tensor(features))
y_data = Variable(torch.Tensor(targets))

class Model(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(10,5)
        self.linear2 = torch.nn.Linear(5,1)

    def forward(self, x):
        l_out1 = self.linear(x)
        y_pred = self.linear2(l_out1)
        return y_pred

model = Model()

criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss(size_average = False)
optim = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = 0.001)

def main():
    for iteration in range(1000):
        y_pred = model(x_data)
        loss = criterion(y_pred, y_data)

        print(iteration, loss.data[0])
        optim.zero_grad()

        loss.backward()
        optim.step()
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

EDIT:

Indeed it seems that this was simply due to the `learning rate` being too high. Setting to `0.00001` fixes convergence issues, albeit giving very slow convergence.

Comment: It may be a good idea to normalize your features prior to running gradient descent.  Normalizing provides faster convergence (usually), and because the gradient at each iteration is based on the magnitude of the features, this will allow you to increase the learning rate.  Do note that upon test time, you will need to normalize the features for your test dataset in the same fashion as you did for the training set.

Comment: Hi raryeng, the features are actually already normalized in the standard way of subtracting mean and dividing by standard deviation. The original data is distributed between zero and roughly 10,000.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're not using a non-linearity between layers, and your network is still Linear.

You can use Relu in order to make it non linear. You can change the forward method like this :

```
...
y_pred = torch.nn.functional.F.relu(self.linear2(l_out1))
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to predict a log(y) instead of y to improve the convergence even more. Also Adam optimizer (adaptive learning rate) should help + BatchNormalization (for example between your linear layers).